# Create XML files dynamically

Tags: objective-c, xml, ipad, xcode4.2, nsxmlparser

I am working on a web service based iPad application. Since the application is fully based on web service I have to create a lot of xml files for web service request. Now I am hardcoding the xml request and passing parameters into it. Is there any way to create xml files dynamically in objective C  ?

Comment: Did you even try to google this?

Comment: @ThomasLindvall Yes I did. If u got any results after googling , pls share here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to hardcode.

You can automate the task by creating xml files.
You can yourself create an xml creator to create files according to your need.

Or ,

You can get help from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/NSXML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001269).

Answer (score 1):

Check out KissXML on github, you create node objects and add children e.t.c. to make XML file out of it, I am using it to make KML files, works  well.